# How to optimize execution time of a function that iterate multiple lists and adding them later to dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, optimization, data-structures

I have an optimization problem, I have a function that calls a salesforce API to get list of attributes associated with each salesforce `sobject` and it returns the list in second or 1.5 second which is not bad and it returns it as JSON. the problem starts when I receive this payload, because I start adding each object attribute received in a dictionary as the `value` of a `key` in it and this function takes from 8 to 12 minutes which is not good at all because after that I should loop on all the dictionary and its values to render them in a view ( more time wasted ).

so my dictionary looks like this             `Dictionary<string, List<string>> sobjects = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

where the dictionary key is the name of the `sobject` and the value is the `list<string>` of attributes associated with that sobject.

this is my function:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllsobjectsAttributes(string accessToken, string domain, List<string> DataSourcesobjects)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> sobjects = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {


                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    
                    foreach (var sobject in DataSourcesobjects)
                    {
                        List<string> fields = new List<string>();
                        sobjects.Add(sobject, fields);
                        var fieldsResult = client.GetAsync("/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/"+sobject+"/describe").Result;
                        string fieldData = fieldsResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        dynamic fieldsDataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(fieldData);
                        JArray fieldslist = fieldsDataObject.fields;
                        foreach (JToken item in fieldslist)
                        {
                            fields.Add(item["name"].ToString());
                        }
                        
                    }
                    return sobjects;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
            
        }
```

and here is my view code:

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> sobject in Model.DataSourceAttributes)
            {
                <optgroup label="@sobject.Key">
                    
                        @foreach (var field in sobject.Value)
                        {
                        <option value="datasourceattribute">@field </option>
                        }
                </optgroup>
            }
```

and here is part of the returned JSON from the API. ( can't post it all since it is too long but you can see how it looks from part of it ).

```
"fields" : [ {
    "aggregatable" : true,
    "aiPredictionField" : false,
    "autoNumber" : false,
    "byteLength" : 18,
    "calculated" : false,
    "calculatedFormula" : null,
    "cascadeDelete" : false,
    "caseSensitive" : false,
    "compoundFieldName" : null,
    "controllerName" : null,
    "createable" : false,
    "custom" : false,
    "defaultValue" : null,
    "defaultValueFormula" : null,
    "defaultedOnCreate" : true,
    "dependentPicklist" : false,
    "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
    "digits" : 0,
    "displayLocationInDecimal" : false,
    "encrypted" : false,
    "externalId" : false,
    "extraTypeInfo" : null,
    "filterable" : true,
    "filteredLookupInfo" : null,
    "formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero" : false,
    "groupable" : true,
    "highScaleNumber" : false,
    "htmlFormatted" : false,
    "idLookup" : true,
    "inlineHelpText" : null,
    "label" : "Account ID",
    "length" : 18,
    "mask" : null,
    "maskType" : null,
    "name" : "Id",
    "nameField" : false,
    "namePointing" : false,
    "nillable" : false,
    "permissionable" : false,
    "picklistValues" : [ ],
    "polymorphicForeignKey" : false,
    "precision" : 0,
    "queryByDistance" : false,
    "referenceTargetField" : null,
    "referenceTo" : [ ],
    "relationshipName" : null,
    "relationshipOrder" : null,
    "restrictedDelete" : false,
    "restrictedPicklist" : false,
    "scale" : 0,
    "searchPrefilterable" : false,
    "soapType" : "tns:ID",
    "sortable" : true,
    "type" : "id",
    "unique" : false,
    "updateable" : false,
    "writeRequiresMasterRead" : false
  }, {
    "aggregatable" : false,
    "aiPredictionField" : false,
    "autoNumber" : false,
    "byteLength" : 0,
    "calculated" : false,
    "calculatedFormula" : null,
    "cascadeDelete" : false,
    "caseSensitive" : false,
    "compoundFieldName" : null,
    "controllerName" : null,
    "createable" : false,
    "custom" : false,
    "defaultValue" : false,
    "defaultValueFormula" : null,
    "defaultedOnCreate" : true,
    "dependentPicklist" : false,
    "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
    "digits" : 0,
    "displayLocationInDecimal" : false,
    "encrypted" : false,
    "externalId" : false,
    "extraTypeInfo" : null,
    "filterable" : true,
    "filteredLookupInfo" : null,
    "formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero" : false,
    "groupable" : true,
    "highScaleNumber" : false,
    "htmlFormatted" : false,
    "idLookup" : false,
    "inlineHelpText" : null,
    "label" : "Deleted",
    "length" : 0,
    "mask" : null,
    "maskType" : null,
    "name" : "IsDeleted",
    "nameField" : false,
    "namePointing" : false,
    "nillable" : false,
    "permissionable" : false,
    "picklistValues" : [ ],
    "polymorphicForeignKey" : false,
    "precision" : 0,
    "queryByDistance" : false,
    "referenceTargetField" : null,
    "referenceTo" : [ ],
    "relationshipName" : null,
    "relationshipOrder" : null,
    "restrictedDelete" : false,
    "restrictedPicklist" : false,
    "scale" : 0,
    "searchPrefilterable" : false,
    "soapType" : "xsd:boolean",
    "sortable" : true,
    "type" : "boolean",
    "unique" : false,
    "updateable" : false,
    "writeRequiresMasterRead" : false
  },
```

**NOTE:**

1. I have 1000 `sobjects` in my dictionary.
2. I can't create the list of fields with a range at first since I have no info about the count of fields returned for each sobject.
3. Fields of each sobject are between 7 to 20 and it may differ from one organization to another.

**Things I tried to make it better :**

passing the list to the function as `ref` instead of copying all the 1000 sobjects list but I heard it is not with any added value since there will be alwats a lookup operation on it every time I add a value.

**Things I still try and test :**

using `Parallel.ForEach()`

Comment: Have you profiled to see how long the 1000 network calls are taking?

Comment: Also, don't create the `fields` list until after you've got the `fieldslist` `JArray`. The reason being that `fieldlist` will have a `Count`, which you can then use as the capacity for your list (i.e. `List<string> fields = new List<string>(capacity: fieldslist.Count);`. This will avoid a whole bunch of needless copying and allocations from the list's backing array having to grow to accommodate all of the fields.

Comment: @JohnH Hello John, it takes 19k to 20k ms , ( 20 seconds )

Comment: @JohnH I will try the capacity part with the fieldlist and update you, hope it make the execution time better

Comment: Also, have a read of the [Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) section for Newtonsoft.Json. Depending on the size of the JSON you're receiving, that could be relevant too.

Comment: @JohnH the link you provided for reading from stream instead of memory is really useful I tried using it and it made a difference in function execution time, it reduced 2 minutes , but I am still checking if I can add this approach to the accepted answer below

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. You threw me off when you replied saying the requests took a total of 20 seconds though, which is why I was looking at the CPU bound code. Anyway, the approach can still be used with the accepted answer. You should still make use of the capacity I suggested above as it's a simple change which improves the performance and readability too. Combining all of these will reduce the time even further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to optimize execution time of [your] function ..." -- I believe that is your main concern.

IMO - the optimization of the lists and dictionaries will not give you substantial speed improvements...  As others noted: your main bottleneck is the api calls -- making 1000 of them.  You would want to run as many as you can concurrently but avoiding port exhaustion.  Then with this suggested implementation - you will want to be using a ConcurrentDictionary.

This is just a (simple) sample of what you might do.  The concept is based off of [this post](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-make-concurrent-requests-with-httpclient/)

I'd be curious to see how much this improves your execution time.

```cs
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllsobjectsAttributes(string accessToken, string domain, List<string> DataSourcesobjects)
        {
            int maxRequests = 10;
            // just one way to try to keep to maxRequests # of api calls at a time
            SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxRequests);

            ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> sobjects = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                    foreach (var sobject in DataSourcesobjects)
                    {
                        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await semaphore.WaitAsync();

                                List<string> fields = new List<string>();
                                sobjects[sobject] = fields;
                                var fieldsResult = await client.GetAsync("/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/" + sobject + "/describe");
                                string fieldData = await fieldsResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                dynamic fieldsDataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(fieldData);
                                JArray fieldslist = fieldsDataObject.fields;
                                foreach (JToken item in fieldslist)
                                {
                                    fields.Add(item["name"].ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
                            {
                                // More error handling?
                                Console.WriteLine($"Failed for sobject: {sobject}");
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                semaphore.Release();
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }));
                    }
                    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

                    return sobjects;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, It really worked, reducing time from 8 minutes to 1.5 , I never thought that the API calling is the bottleneck here. but it is the first time for me to do this approach, I mean never thought that network calling can be done in parallel from many threads

Comment: also I changed the API calls to 25 instead of 10 and it was faster. don't know how far I can go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the line setting var fieldResults and hard code the fieldData to the big json string. Runnig this will prove, or not, that the time is lost in the network call. I suspect that is the culprit and the code will be a lot faster. If that is the case then you need to rethink how you are doing it. E.g in the ui have one dropdown to select the sobject then another to select the field.